# Can I make a link fill its parent without using display:block or display:inline-block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

---

**See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmuupxhn/2/)**

I want to make the `.newslink` links all the way to the borders of the `.content` divs.

I have a slideshow of different content that gets messed up either if I set the a tag around the div or if I apply `display:block` / `display:inline-block` to the `a` element.

Right now the links are only around the image and text because of the 15px padding in `.content`. You can check this by hovering your mouse over the div (near the border) compared to over the image and text area. I want each link to completely fill the surrounding div.

Is it in this case possible to accomplish without setting the `a` tag around the div or applying `display:block` / `display:inline-block` to the a element?

Comment: How about `display:inline-block`?

Comment: summarize your problem...

Comment: can you put this in a fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: if you read only the text you have a pretty good summary. Just included the code to make it concrete.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3L16146r/4/

Comment: @2L84F8 I know I can figure it out from your text.. but I'd understand the problem much quicker seeing a fiddle.. the point is, people here want to help on their own time and for free.. as part of this helpful and useful community you are asked as a questioner to save as much time as you can for those helping you.. thats all.

Comment: @webkit I'm trying to set up a good fiddle but I ran in to some trouble there as well heh... I'm not being arrogant, doing my best here. Have patience ;)

Comment: I hope this edit made it clearer, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmuupxhn/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tqryvu5/**

Firstly, let's get rid of the Table markup as you're not marking up a table.

```
<div id="tableNews">
    <div class="cell2">

        <div id="slideshow">

            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" id="rightLink1" class="newsLink" target="_blank">
                    <div class="picDiv">
                        <img id="rightPic1" class="pic2" src="http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/5238c9c5ecad047f12b2751a/internet-famous-grumpy-cat-just-landed-an-endorsement-deal-with-friskies.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <h2 id="title1">title 1</h2>
                        <p id="rightBoxSubText1">asdasd</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

To achieve the effect you should apply the padding to the anchor link as this wraps both the images and text (essentially forming the border). Here's the part to take note of:

```
.newsLink {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

As it's an inline element you will need to set it to display:block in order to make it wrap the elements inside it. If you correctly apply the style to the surrounding elements then setting it to display:block will not effect the layout.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am using table structure to build my page, just didn't include the rest since it's not relevant. I'm well aware of that a solution to make an inline element a block is with the display:block. However, as I described in my question, it messes up the slideshow functionality, which also didn't work in your fiddle. I'm looking for an alternative, seems like there is none :/

Comment: @2L84F8 I have updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8tqryvu5/3/ - to illustrate that this layout does not break the slider functionality and it can indeed work with the anchor set to block.

Comment: hmm, so the table is what causes the problem?

Comment: The table doesn't cause the problem. I suggest ed removing it as you are not marking up tabular data. It's a semantics suggestion. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that I got right the whole thing but I think you can achieve this by using

```
.newsLink{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;background:red}
```

It will take the wodth of the slideshow, which is the relative element. If you want it to take the size of the .content and not more you will have to add a wrap in display block around you  tag

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8c041xy7/5/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to absolute position anchor tag

```
.newsLink {
display: block;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```